# Why is the AI vibrating when it moves

Tags: javascript, debugging, p5.js

```js
let playerX;
let playerY;
let playerSize = 15;
let playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10;
let Newcelltimer = 0;
let cell = []
let zoom = 1;
let n = 0;
let Xgrid = 600;
let Ygrid = 600;
let cpu = [];
let x = 0;
let y = 10;
let OffSetX = [];
let OffSetY = [];
let CPUteam = 2;

function setup() {
  smooth();
  frameRate(999)
  createCanvas(600, 450);
  playerX = 500;
  playerY = 100;

}

function draw() {
  let cellDist = [];
  let cpuDist = [];
  background(220);
  push();
  //Changes the FOV depending on your size
  let Newzoom = 10 / playerSize
  let newnewZoom = 1.3 * lerp(0.9, 10 / playerSize, 0.5)
  Newzoom = lerp(zoom, Newzoom, 0.3)
  translate(Xgrid / 2, Ygrid / 2 - 50);
  scale(newnewZoom)
  translate(-playerX, -playerY);

  // Player's speed
  playerSpeed = round((playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10000) / 1000
  Newcelltimer++;

  //Adds in new cells
  if (Newcelltimer % 40 == 0) {
    cell.push(ceil(random(0 - Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)),
    ceil(random(0 - Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)))
  }
  //Adds in new AI's
  if (Newcelltimer % 200 == 0) {
    cpu.push(ceil(random(-Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)), ceil(random(-Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)), 20, CPUteam)
    OffSetX.push(ceil(random(0, 1000000)))
    OffSetY.push(ceil(random(1000000, 2000000)))
    CPUteam++;
  }
  //Creates AI when you start playing
  if (Newcelltimer == 1 || Newcelltimer == 2) {
    cpu.push(ceil(random(-Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)), ceil(random(-Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)), 20, CPUteam)
    OffSetX.push(ceil(random(0, 1000000)))
    OffSetY.push(ceil(random(1000000, 2000000)))

    cell.push(ceil(random(0 - Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)),
    ceil(random(0 - Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)))
    CPUteam++;
  }
  //Checks if cell is eaten
  for (let i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {
    let d = int(dist(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], playerX, playerY))
    if (d <= playerSize / 2) {
      playerSize += 5;
      cell.splice(i * 2, 2)
      celliseaten = true;
    }
    else{
      fill(0,255,255,180);
      circle(i*2,i*2+1,8);
    }
  }
  //The cells disappear after a bit
  if (Newcelltimer % 200 == 0) {
    cell.splice(0, 2)
  }

  //Everything to do with the AI system
  for (let j = 0; j < (cpu.length / 4); j++) {

    let cpuDist = [];

    let distance = int(dist(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], playerX, playerY)) //Distance between AI and player
    if (distance <= playerSize / 2 && cpu[j * 4 + 2] < playerSize) {
      playerSize += floor(cpu[j * 4 + 2]);
      cpu.splice(j * 4, 4)
    }
    else if(distance<=cpu[j*4+2]/2&&cpu[j*4+2]<playerSize)
    {
    //You lose
    }
    //Checks if AI ate AI
    for (let m = 0; m < cpu.length / 4; m++) {
      //Makes sure the AI's isn't the AI in the "j" loop
      if (m != j) {
        //Checks if the Ai's are on the same team
        if (cpu[j * 4 + 3] % 2 != cpu[m * 4 + 3] % 2) {

          distant = dist(cpu[m * 4], cpu[m * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1])
          let higher = (cpu[m * 4 + 2] > cpu[j * 4 + 2]) ? cpu[m * 4 + 2] : cpu[j * 4 + 2];

          if (higher > distant) {
            if (cpu[m * 4 + 2] > cpu[j * 4 + 2]) {
              cpu[m * 4 + 2] += cpu[j * 4 + 2]
              cpu.splice(j * 4, 4)
            } else {
              cpu[j * 4 + 2] += cpu[m * 4 + 2]
              cpu.splice(m * 4, 4)
            } //Else
          } //If
          //If AI didn't eat another AI, return the distance
          else {
            cpuDist.push(distant);
          } //Else
        } //If
      } //If
    } //For

    let ClosestCpu = min(cpuDist);
    let ClosestCpupos;
    //Index value of the closest cpu (NOT WORKINGS)
    for (var q = 0; q < cpu.length / 4; q++) {
      if (ClosestCpu == int(dist(cpu[q * 4], cpu[q * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]))) {
        ClosestCpupos = q;
        break;
      }
    }
    //Checks if AI ate cell
    for (let n = 0; n < cell.length / 2; n++) {
      let dis = int(dist(cell[n * 2], cell[n * 2 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]))
      if (dis <= cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2) {
        cpu[j * 4 + 2] += 5;
        cell.splice(n * 2, 2)
      } else {
        //If it didn't eat the cell, does the same idea with the AI from before
        cellDist.push(dis)
      }
    }
    let ClosestCell = min(cellDist);
    let ClosestCellpos;
    for (let r = 0; r < cell.length / 2; r++) {
      if (ClosestCell == int(dist(cell[r * 2], cell[r * 2 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]))) {
        ClosestCellpos = r;
        break;
      }
    }
    //AI sppeed
    let amp = round((cpu[j * 4 + 2] / Math.pow(cpu[j * 4 + 2], 1.44)) * 70000) / 7000;

    if (dist(playerX, playerY, cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]) < 150 && playerSize > cpu[j * 4 + 2]) {

      let distXpos = cpu[j * 4]-playerX;
      let distYpos = cpu[j * 4 + 1]-playerY;

      let higherVal = (abs(distXpos) > abs(distYpos)) ? distXpos : distYpos;

      let MultVal = 150/abs(higherVal);

      distXpos*=MultVal;
      distYpos*=MultVal;

      distXpos = map(distXpos, -150, 150, -1, 1);
      distYpos = map(distYpos, -150, 150, -1, 1);
      cpu[j * 4] += distXpos * amp;
      cpu[j * 4 + 1] += distYpos * amp;
    } else if (dist(playerX, playerY, cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]) < 150 && playerSize < cpu[j * 4 + 2]) {
      let distXpos = cpu[j * 4]-playerX;
      let distYpos = cpu[j * 4 + 1]-playerY;

      let higherVal = (abs(distXpos) > abs(distYpos)) ? distXpos : distYpos;

      let MultVal = 150/abs(higherVal);

      distXpos*=MultVal;
      distYpos*=MultVal;

      distXpos = map(distXpos, -150, 150, -1, 1);
      distYpos = map(distYpos, -150, 150, -1, 1);
      cpu[j * 4] -= distXpos * amp;
      cpu[j * 4 + 1] -= distYpos * amp; 
    } 
    else if (dist(cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4], cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]) < 150 && cpu[j * 4 + 2] > cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4 + 2]) {

      let distXpos = cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4] - cpu[j * 4];
      let distYpos = cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4 + 1] - cpu[j * 4 + 1];

      let higherVal = (abs(distXpos) > abs(distYpos)) ? distXpos : distYpos;

      let MultVal = 150/abs(higherVal);

      distXpos*=MultVal;
      distYpos*=MultVal;

      distXpos = map(distXpos, -150, 150, -1, 1);
      distYpos = map(distYpos, -150, 150, -1, 1);
      cpu[j * 4] += distXpos * amp;
      cpu[j * 4 + 1] += distYpos * amp;
    } else if (dist(cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4], cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]) < 150 && cpu[j * 4 + 2] > cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4 + 2]) {

      let distXpos = cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4] - cpu[j * 4];
      let distYpos = cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4 + 1] - cpu[j * 4 + 1];

      let higherVal = (abs(distXpos) > abs(distYpos)) ? distXpos : distYpos;

      let MultVal = 150/abs(higherVal);

      distXpos*=MultVal;
      distYpos*=MultVal;

      distXpos = map(distXpos, -150, 150, -1, 1);
      distYpos = map(distYpos, -150, 150, -1, 1);
      cpu[j * 4] -= distXpos * amp;
      cpu[j * 4 + 1] -= distYpos * amp;
    } else if (dist(cell[ClosestCellpos * 2], cell[ClosestCellpos * 2 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]) < 150) {

      let distXpos = cell[ClosestCellpos * 2] - cpu[j * 4];
      let distYpos = cell[ClosestCellpos * 2 + 1] - cpu[j * 4 + 1];

      let higherVal = (abs(distXpos) > abs(distYpos)) ? distXpos : distYpos;

      let MultVal = 150/abs(higherVal);

      distXpos*=MultVal;
      distYpos*=MultVal;

      distXpos = map(distXpos, -150, 150, -1, 1);
      distYpos = map(distYpos, -150, 150, -1, 1);
      cpu[j * 4] += distXpos * amp;
      cpu[j * 4 + 1] += distYpos * amp;
    } else {
      x += 0.003;
      y += 0.003;
      let offsetX = map(noise(x + OffSetX[j]), 0, 1, -1, 1) * amp;
      let offsetY = map(noise(y + OffSetY[j]), 0, 1, -1, 1) * amp;
      cpu[j * 4] += offsetX;
      cpu[j * 4 + 1] += offsetY;
    }
    if (cpu[j * 4 + 3] % 2 == 0) {
      fill(0, 0, 255)
      circle(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4 + 2]);
    } else {
      fill(255, 0, 0)
      circle(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4 + 2])
    } // Else
  } //Cpu for


  //Draws player
  fill(255, 255, 0)
  circle(playerX, playerY, playerSize)
  pop();
}
```

The problem is that when the player is chasing the AI, and the AI is running, the AI is vibrating when it's running away. Also, closestCpupos is undefined for some reason, that's not my question, and something I'll fix later or ask another question, the latter probably the case. I've put in a LOT of code, so I put a comment on most stuff. The problem is probably somewhere in the `for(var j = 0;j<cpu.length/4;j++)` loop. Not sure if this code will run in the snipper either, I probably deleted something which won't make it run in the snippet tool, and the code has too many nested loops.

- https://editor.p5js.org/Meowmeow/sketches/XTH-hArn6 The full program, with nothing deleted
- If the AI chases the player, it doesn't vibrate
- The AI chase AI isn't working, that'll be asked in another question
- The problem is probably in the CPU for loop
- The array is confusing, and should probably be a 2d array, but to try to explain it: The 1d array is in "Groups" of 4's, the first number is the X pos, the second is 2 Y pos, third is size, fourth is Team blue or Team red (If the 4th value %2 is 0, it's blue, else its 1). So an array of CPUs could look like `[100,150,25,3,250,600,15,4]` then you would do a for loop, starting at 0, going to the length/4, then you draw the AI's, first AI would be at 100,150, size 25, Team Blue. the second AI would be at 200,600, size 26, team Red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the AI moves more quickly and more efficiently than the player. Suppose the CPU moves 3 pixels per frame and the player moves 1. Now consider the following:

- The CPU is 149 pixels away from the player, so it moves 3 pixels away from the player and the player moves 1 pixel toward the CPU
- Next frame: CPU is 151 pixels away, so it reverts to its normal behavior.
- Next frame: the player has moved closer, so it reverts to being chased.
- repeat

This alternating between states is what causes the vibration you see. How do you solve this? One solution is to give each CPU a boolean value for being chased. You can set this to true when the CPU comes within 150 of the player, and then set it back to false when it gets to be 200 away. That way, it won't oscillate because it needs to move 50 pixels in order to change behavior. In order to do this, you need to change all of the instances of `j * 4` to `j * 5` and give `cpu[j * 5 + 4]` an initial boolean value. Here's my solution for testing:

```js
if (cpu[j * 5 + 4]) {//if currently running away
  //continue running away if smallerthan player and still within 200
  cpu[j * 5 + 4] = dist(cpu[j * 5], cpu[j * 5 + 1], playerX, playerY) < 200 && 
                   playerSize > cpu[j * 5 + 2];
} else {//if not currently running away
  //start running away if smaller than player and within 150
  cpu[j * 5 + 4] = dist(cpu[j * 5], cpu[j * 5 + 1], playerX, playerY) < 150 && 
                   playerSize > cpu[j * 5 + 2];
}
if (cpu[j * 5 + 4]) {
  //your running away code...
}//...
```

I *highly* encourage you to use classes. If you make a class for your CPUs, you can  make a method for each of the things you want to do. Then you can have an array of CPUs and iterate through it, doing all the things you need it to do. It just makes the code more organized.

Comment: Wouldn't it be still vibrating between being False and Undefined?

Comment: @user15302406 No, it wouldn't. It will be true whenever it is within 150, and false whenever it is further than 200, but when it is between those, it will just maintain whatever value it had previously.